# Does CS-CART's backend use 960.gs? (MultiVendor v4.2.4)

Tags: html, css, web, frontend, cs-cart

I want to modify some look and feel of CS-CART's backend, but I don't know how start yet.
I check the generated standaloneXXX.css, and it says:

> The complete list of files it's generated from:
>   design/backend/css/lib/ui/jqueryui.css
>   design/backend/css/styles.less
>   design/backend/css/glyphs.css
>   design/backend/css/addons/help_tutorial/styles.less
>   design/backend/css/addons/seo/styles.less
>   design/backend/css/addons/call_requests/styles.less
>   design/backend/css/addons/discussion/styles.less
>   design/backend/css/addons/hybrid_auth/styles.css
>   design/backend/css/addons/twigmo/styles.css

but I notice that there are some file like 960.gs and bootstrap in **design\backend\css\lib**
[image]

what is those 960 and bootstrap file used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [this](https://www.hungryweb.net/cs-cart-themes/modern-backend-theme.html) or you can start modifying `design/backend/css/styles.less`